# Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException : Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH

Tags: sonarqube, xunit, sonarscanner

1. I have Integrated SonarQube
2. Installed Visual Studio 2022 EnterPrise Edition - Test Project in c# code base
3. Installed the coverlet for Unit Test Code Coverage for Test Project
4. with command line getting the below error:
   coverlet "./Application.Tests/bin/Debug/Application.Tests.dll" --target "dotnet" --targetargs "test "./Application.Tests/Application.Tests.csproj" --no-build" -f=opencover -o="coverage.xml"

Error Message:
Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException :Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH and COR_PROFILER environment variables.
Stack Trace:
at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.IntelliTraceInstrumentationProvider.ResolveProfilerPath()
at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.IntelliTraceInstrumentationProvider.Initialize()
at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationRuntime.InitializeUnitTestIsolationInstrumentationProvider()
at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimRuntime.CreateContext()

Getting error while running coverlet command line
coverlet "./Application.Tests/bin/Debug/Application.Tests.dll" --target "dotnet" --targetargs "test "./Application.Tests/Application.Tests.csproj" --no-build" -f=opencover -o="coverage.xml"

** Error Message:**
Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException :Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH and COR_PROFILER environment variables.

Expected: Need to overcome from this error.

Answer (score 0):

**For dot net core Test Project**
coverlet "./Application.Tests/bin/Debug/Application.Tests.dll" --target "dotnet" --targetargs "test "./Application.Tests/Application.Tests.csproj" --no-build" -f=opencover -o="coverage.xml"

**For dot net framework Test Project**
coverlet "./Application.Tests/bin/Debug/Application.Tests.dll" --target "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" --targetargs  "./Application.Tests/bin/Debug/Application.Tests.dll" -f=opencover -o="coverage.xml"